# OpenId Connect: adding extra/custom parameter at the token endpoint call

Tags: apache, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

With our IdP server team we discussed while implementing code authorization flow with OIDC and they proposed to add a new http/query parameter to the http call to token endpoint named "resourceServer", would you say it should be possible to OIDC implementations such as apache httpd oidc module (certified openid) to add such a parameter?
Thank you

Comment: what you mean is, "Is it possible to add new parameter to token endpoint " ?

Answer (score 3):

OpenID Connect being an extension built on OAuth 2.0, you must check with specification to see whether this violate it.

Following is mentioned about token endpoint through OAuth 2.0,

> **[3.2.  Token Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2)**
>
> ... Parameters sent without a value MUST be treated as if they were
> omitted from the request.  The authorization server MUST ignore
> unrecognized request parameters.  Request and response parameters
> MUST NOT be included more than once.

If you decide to alter and add a parameter to your token request, then the only requirement is to your authorization server to accept that parameter. Else your authorization server will ignore it.

Also, extra parameters can be seen in major OpenID Connect adaptations. For example, [MS Azure authorization request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#get-access-tokens) contains **resource** parameter to state the protected resource that access token will be used against. It is similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can add additional parameter to connect endpoint by providing acr_value, here is a reference link. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html
How I have achieved this is below:-
[image]

Comment: `domain` is not listed as one of the keys in the specification. Does this mean any key can be used or this could be a violation of the specification ?

Comment: this is the key against I want to receive value you can have your key. Its key value pair